# Is it possible to have a user enter integers and add them using a while loop in python?

Tags: python

This is for one of my assignments.
Here is the question just for clarity on what I am trying to do. Please do not give me the answer, just if you could help me understand what I need to do.

> Write a Python program that uses a WHILE loop.  The program must prompt the user to enter an integer number.  The value must be added to a total.  The loop must continue until the total exceeds 45.  After the loop, the average of the numbers must be calculated.  The program must display each of the input values, as well as the sum of all values and the average value.
>
> *** enhancement, replace the user prompt with a random number selector.

This is the current code I am using:

```py
num = int(input('Enter as many integers as you want: '))
numList =num.split() 
print('All entered numbers ', numList)
sum = 0
while num >= 45: 
    print('Sum of all numbers ', sum)
    avg = sum / num
    print('Average of all numbers ', avg)
```

This, of course, is not working, I have figured out how to do it with a for loop ( from the internet ) I just cannot seem to understand how to link the input function with the while loop.

Comment: Sounds like you need to prompt the user for a number _inside_ the `while` - one int at a time.

Comment: First, initialize a variable to store the total.
Next, start the while loop.
Next, while inside the loop, ask for the user input.
Next, while inside the loop, add to total.
Next, when loop exits, perform the average and other calcs.

Answer (score 2):

You want to read numbers *one* at a time, until the sum exceeds 45.

```
total = 0
num_list = []
while total < 45:
    num = int(input(...))
    num_list.append(num)
    total += num

# Now compute the average and report the sum and averages
```

To make sure the last number is not added to the list if that would put the total over 45,

```
total = 0
num_list = []
while True:
    num = int(input(...))
    new_total = total + num
    if new_total > 45:
        break
    num_list.append(num)
    total = new_total
```

Comment: I id like this first, but the will exceed 45, as you sum before checking

Comment: My reading of the assignment says that's what you want, but I can update the answer to do it the other way as well.

Comment: That's my read, too. An intro CS assignment will surely not want students to write `while True` and `if ...: break`.

Comment: I think it's ok to go over 45: _The loop must continue until the total **exceeds** 45._

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Good point; `<` should probably be `<=` in the first solution.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help !! This will more then suffice. Getting there with the understanding too :)

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop should be used to get values from the user : *While the total of the given values is lower than 45, ask the user for another value*

```
numList = []
total = 0

while True:
    num = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
    if (total + num) > 45:
        break
    numList.append(num)
    total = total + num

avg = total / len(numList)
print('Sum of all numbers ', total)
print('Average of all numbers ', avg)
```