# How do I gather information from each loop in a while loop python

Tags: python

I want to gather information from a while loop each time it loops over. For example, if you have a while loop that runs forever and encases an input asking for a number, and you add the numbers over time, how should I do that? Example:

```
while True:
  a = int(input("Enter a number "))
  a = a + a
```

Is there any way to do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Put a variable outside of the loop

Comment: Could you clarify what that means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a user enter integers and add them using a while loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849323/is-it-possible-to-have-a-user-enter-integers-and-add-them-using-a-while-loop-in)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
total = 0
while True:
  a = int(input("Enter a number"))
  total = total + a

  print("The sum is ", total)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name. It hides the built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
while True:
  a = int(input("Enter a number "))
  total = total + a

  print(f"The total is {total}")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.